# Is there a way of 'cooling' smoke over time?

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

I want to make my smoke simulation send smoke up, but eventually that smoke begins to fall, simulating the smoke losing thermal energy over the period of time it exists. How can I go about this in Blender and, ideally, is there a way of editing a curve of *the derivative of temperature* to *time*, so that I can control how it cools?

The only thing is, I don't think it would be as simple as editing a dope sheet, since I want the smoke to continuously do this. As in, the smoke immediately coming from the emitter is warm throughout the timeline, while the bits smoke that have lasted a few seconds get colder. I think directly using the temperature in a dope sheet would just cause the emitter to change the temperature of the smoke immediately coming out of the emitter while also having that smoke remain at the same temperature throughout the timeline, which is not what I want.

Comment: In the current blender smoke system, it is not possible to add a time-dependent temperature gradient (thermal energy loss). 1) However, if you use a negative value for temperature difference (in the domain) that will allow smoke to settle down (fall downward) on an obstacle object or domain bottom. Then using dissolve option (in the domain) and a wind force to achieve something like you ask in the question. 2) The second way is to use particles. Because you can damp the velocity of the particles over a period of time so that they settle on a floor and use these particles as the smoke emitter.

Comment: @3DSinghVFX Yeah, I was hoping for smoke that would rise because of the heat then slowly fall. I imagine I program the behaviour into a particle system though.

Comment: If you want the smoke to rise for small time period and then fall down or settle down, I think it is possible with smoke system and wind force.